# How to set the cost argument in the adist and agrep function?

Tags: r, agrep

I need some help to understand the arguments of these functions. I took the example from the help.

```
## To see the transformation counts for the Levenshtein distance:
drop(attr(adist("kitten", "sitting", counts = TRUE), "counts"))
# ins del sub 
#   1   0   2
```

ins, stands for insertions; del for deletions; and sub for substitutions.

```
## To see the transformation sequences:
attr(adist(c("kitten", "sitting"), counts = TRUE), "trafos")
#      [,1]      [,2]     
# [1,] "MMMMMM"  "SMMMSMI"
# [2,] "SMMMSMD" "MMMMMMM"
```

From this is easy to see that while comparing the string one visa vie the string two, it finds `SMMMSMI`; 2 substitutions and 1 insertion, in total the distance should be three.

```
adist("kitten", "sitting", costs = list(ins=1, del=0, sub=1), partial = F)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    3
```

This is what I don't get, why when I set the cost of insertions equal to zero, the outcome is zero in the total distance. I would expect to be 2, because of the number of substitutions.

```
adist("kitten", "sitting", costs = list(ins=0, del=0, sub=1), partial = F)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This is easier to explain if you take a look at the actual counts while specifying the costs for each operation as you did:

```
drop(attr(adist("kitten", "sitting", costs = list(ins=0, del=0, sub=1), 
                 partial = F, counts = T), "counts"))

# ins del sub 
#   6   5   0
```

So you see that instead of:

```
# ins del sub 
#   1   0   2
```

The number of operations for insertions, deletions and substitutions has changed when you specify a set of different cost parameters from the default. This makes sense since there are more than one way to transform one string to another and the distance from `adist` is, according to `?adist`:

> a generalized Levenshtein (edit) distance, giving the
>   minimal possibly weighted number of insertions, deletions and
>   substitutions needed to transform one string into another.

According to this statement, there should be an optimization under hood to minimize the number of operations weighted by the `cost` parameters, so if we specify `insertions` and `deletions` cost parameters to be zero, then it will not use `substitution` operation any more since the previous two operations are obviously less costly and indeed it uses 6 insertions and 5 deletions to complete the transformation which ends up with a zero distance since the cost for these two operations are zero.